# Inner span overflows past outer span

Tags: html, css

I need your help,

I can't seem to figure out as to why my inner span overflows past my outer span?

Here is a pic of the problem:

[image]

Here is the HTML and CSS markup:

```html
<span style="border: 1px solid blue; display:inline-block; position: relative; width: 100%;">
     <span style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid red; text-align: right; width:100%">
       test
     </span>
</span>
```

Comment: What do you mean "overflows past outer span"? The right hand edges are touching, not overflowing.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/s1o36tn9/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```css
span{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<span style="border: 1px solid blue; display:inline-block; position: relative; width: 100%;">
     <span style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid red; text-align: right; width:100%">test</span>
</span>
```

apply this css rule:

```
span{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

> border-box :  The width and height properties (and min/max properties)
>   includes content, padding and border, but not the margin

You can find more about `box-sizing` [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<span style="border: 1px solid blue; display:inline-block; position: relative; width: 99%;padding: 5px;">
 <span style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid red; text-align: right; width: 100%;">test</span>
```